# Store a value from database add check if a element get added end of list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have connect to a database and get values, this is absolutly fine.
But what I´m trying to do is to execute a function when a value adds to the end of the list.

What I actually want, is to compare

`len(oldlist)` with `len(newlist)`

```
if len(newlist > oldlist):
   Message.send(m)
```

I´ve even tried to use append:

```
if newlist.append(ValueFromDB):
  pass
(can a if statment like this work?)
```

But everything leads to the same problem, I awlays get the same len value from from DB so it should be aaway to check if a new value adds to the end of the list, and if it does

```
Message.send(m)
```

I need some ideas to actually pull this off, is there any pythonic way to execute this? I know the questionis a bit messy, but I´m bit confused =)

Comment: Which list are you talking about? What does it have to do with the database?

Comment: Please put the code which queries the data. I assume the result of this query is added to the list. Is the query in a loop of some sort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are having this problem because, `oldlist` and `newlist`
are the same `object`, check this out:

```
newlist = [1, 2, 3]
oldlist = newlist

newlist.append(4)
print(oldlist)  # [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(id(newlist) == id(oldlist))  # True
print(len(newList) == len(oldList))  # True
```

So when you keep track of the `oldlist` use a copy of the original list:

```
newlist = [1, 2, 3]
oldlist = newlist[:]  # create a copy

newlist.append(4)
print(oldlist)  # [1, 2, 3]
print(id(newlist) == id(oldlist))  # False
print(len(newList) == len(oldList)) # False
```

Comment: The Id function did it! dude thanks! this not just solved the problem, I actually learned a usefull function :)

Comment: @The.B just to clarify thing sometime even if the lists contains the same elements the ID is always different.  if you move the condition of ID before adding the element 4 the condition is always False because they are different object in memory. so are you comparing the element of list or just the length?

Comment: just the length, the Query it self have distinct values, but the program will send a message if the list size expand. But the list can also get values deleted, will the Id function affect if the listSize gets empty? and if it get empty of mimimize with 1 the program should't send mail.

Comment: No when you use a copy the ID are always different the condition is always False, this why I told you to create a copy of the list so when you change the `newList` the `oldList` will not be changed. and If you wan to to send a message to show witch element is deleted saving the length alone will not help. The problem with your code is you didn't save a copy of newList in the oldList you saved the same object.

Comment: @The.B when I used the id to show you that they are different object i didn't mean that you should use it, always keep comparing the `len(newList) == len(oldList)` and I was going to explain that if you don't need to show information about the deleted element no need keep a copy of the list just save it's length, witch the accepted answer is doing ^^

Comment: It´s correct, I dont whant to show information about the deleted elemt, only that the length is diffrent.This is doing what I whant. I just put a elif statement ´elif oldlist == 0: True. and it works.

Comment: @The.B can you update your question and show the code where you define oldlist and where you add or remove a element from the newlist. Like that I could help you more and explain what is the best solution for you in term of memory cost and execution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're accessing the database - nor how you're adding data to the list - but something like this should work.

Basically, you track the length of the list in a separate variable, and then each time you add something to the list, you check to see if the `len(list)` has increased in comparison to that variable.

I.e.

```
_list = []
_list_len = 0
while True:
    value = input("Input value of just press enter to skip...")
    if len(value) > 0: 
        _list.append(value)

    if len(_list) > _list_len:
        print("Sending message...")
        _list_len = len(_list)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Input value of just press enter to skip...1
Sending message...
Input value of just press enter to skip...2
Sending message...
Input value of just press enter to skip...
Input value of just press enter to skip...
Input value of just press enter to skip...3
Sending message...
Input value of just press enter to skip...
```